# Wireshark showing Cloudflare WARP packets as DLEP instead of WireGuard or UDP

Tags: networking, wireshark, network-protocols, cloudflare

[image]
[image]

From what I've found so far, [DLEP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-manet-dlep/05/) belongs to [Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/solutions/industries/docs/gov/aag_dlep.pdf) ? and Cloudflare WARP is [supposed to use WireGuard](https://blog.cloudflare.com/build-your-own-private-network-on-cloudflare/)

I need help understanding why I'm seeing DLEP packets in WireShark instead of UDP or WireGuard.

I'm aware that WireShark can sometimes mislabel packets, but not sure if it's the case this time.

so maybe this is an experiment in the WARP? I'm using beta version of Cloudflare WARP btw.

Comment: Was the destinaton port number `854`?

Comment: the source port is 864, unfortunately I forgot to take a note of the port, now Cloudflare WARP+ packets are being listed as UDP. I really need to know if Wireshark is being stupid or WARP+ uses multiple protocols, or something else is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WARP traffic in that capture appears to be using UDP port 854, which is registered to DLEP. Wireshark can only use the port number to know what next-layer decoder to use (Wireshark doesn't have some kind of AI/ML/heuristic traffic type recognizer), so it's using the DLEP decoder. Since this is not actually DLEP traffic, the decoder is flagging all kinds of weird/wrong things, which confirms that this is not actually DLEP. When keying off the well-known uses of a given port yields the wrong results like this, you can tell Wireshark to use a different decoder for that traffic. You should tell Wireshark that you want to use the WARP decoder for this.

Comment: sorry but where can you see the port number from screenshots above? today I'm checking Wireshark and Cloudflare WARP+ packets are now being listed as UDP and all of their destination ports 864. I didn't change anything in Wireshark or WARP app, but all of a sudden the traffic is listen as different protocol. not sure what is going on. there is no problem whatsoever, I just want to understand the situation and know the why.

Comment: @Jameschad The UDP destination port is the two-byte big endian value at offset 0x24 in the packet in your screenshot. It has value 0x0356, which is decimal 854.

Comment: Thank you, so Wireshark correctly recognized the traffic type and Cloudflare WARP+ was 100% using DLEP. interesting, I searched but didn't find any documentation or mention of DLEP protocol usage in WARP+.

Comment: @Jameschad No, it was never using DLEP. It was using the port that is normally used for DLEP, so there was no way for Wireshark to know that it wasn't DLEP. I'll update my answer to make it more clear.